# Select the first h2 near a element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm really new in JS and JQuery and I'm failing in select a element to animate, this is my HTML

```
    <div class="box-product">
      <h2>Light</h2>
      <figure>
        <img src="img/boxes/light.jpg" alt="Pepper Box Light" title="Pepper Box Light" />
        <figcaption>
          Versão light, porém igualmente apimentada da nossa PepperBox, para quem quer se divertir com seu amor</figcaption>
      </figure>          
    </div><!-- box-product -->
```

I'm trying to select the `h2` when the user hover the `figure`, so that's my best guess:

```
    $('.box-product figure').hover(function() {
    $('.box-product').closest('h2').animate({color: 'f00'}, 'slow')
}, function() {
    $('.box-product').closest('h2').animate({color: 'inherit'}, 'slow')
});
```

But nothing happens, so, I need some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest():`

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

You can use `prev()` method:

```
$('.box-product figure').hover(function() {
   $(this).prev().animate({color: '#f00'}, 'slow')
}, function() {
   $(this).prev().animate({color: 'inherit'}, 'slow')
});
```

or:

```
$('.box-product figure').hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings('h2').animate({color: '#f00'}, 'slow')
}, function() {
   $(this).siblings('h2').animate({color: 'inherit'}, 'slow')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, this worked but like I said up there, the color was set to `f00` and without correct it to `#f00` nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) since the desired `h2` is the previous sibling of `figure`, [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches the ancestors of the selected items for a match.

```
$('.box-product figure').hover(function() {
    $h2 = $(this).prev('h2');
    $h2.animate({color: '#f00'}, 'slow')
}, function() {
    $h2.animate({color: '#000'}, 'slow')
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/zQZZh/)

Answer (score 1):

[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) returns elements up in the dom tree, amongst the parent nodes. You will need [`siblings("h2")`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or just [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the element before the hovered `<figure>`:

```
$('.box-product figure').hover(function() {
     $(this).prev().animate({color: 'f00'}, 'slow')
}, function() {
    $(this).prev().animate({color: 'inherit'}, 'slow')
});
```

Starting with the selector `$('.box-product')`, you could use [`find("h2")`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`children("h2")`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), but that would select all of them in the whole document. If your box were unique, you could use something like `$("#box-product h2")` as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks, the `prev()` worked too, and as I said up there, I type the wrong color, without change it to `#f00` nothing happened and no error are displayed on Firefox JS inspector.

Answer (score 1):

`h2` is the siblings of the `figure`.

```
$('.box-product figure').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('h2').animate({color: '#f00'}, 'slow')
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('h2').animate({color: 'inherit'}, 'slow')
});
```

Comment: Damm, I tried all the answers and nothing changed, then I see the color `f00`, just put the `#` and this worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Nearest first element...

```
​$('h2').siblings(':first')​;​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PvqWQ/)

Answer (score 0):

*closest()* method finds closest match from parents hierarchy, not from child elements nor siblings.

In your case you need to just find child element from parent. Like this:

```
 $('.box-product figure').hover(function() {
     $(this).closest('.box-product').find('h2').animate({color: 'f00'}, 'slow')
 }, function() {
     $(this).closest('.box-product').find('h2').animate({color: 'inherit'}, 'slow')
 });
```